# CSS animation fails first then works as intended

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm getting myself working on a simple page. It will have a list of disciplines and as they are selected the information will be displayed below.

the pen [here](https://codepen.io/TunaMac/pen/JMWxBO) shows the functionality I am looking for however the animation works when it loads initially but for all the other sections the first time they are displayed there is no animation. After that they display with the animation no problem.

```
@keyframes fadeIn {

    0% {
        transform: scale(0.9);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

#content1, #content2, #content3, #content4, #content5 {
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: fadeIn 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: fadeIn 0.7s ease-in-out;
    animation: fadeIn 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

#tab1[type="radio"]:not(:checked) ~ #content1,
#tab2[type="radio"]:not(:checked) ~ #content2,
#tab3[type="radio"]:not(:checked) ~ #content3,
#tab4[type="radio"]:not(:checked) ~ #content4,
#tab5[type="radio"]:not(:checked) ~ #content5 {
    display: none;
}

#tab1[type="radio"]:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2[type="radio"]:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3[type="radio"]:checked ~ #content3,
#tab4[type="radio"]:checked ~ #content4,
#tab5[type="radio"]:checked ~ #content5 {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the initial animation has already been triggered while your elements were invisible.
Setting their `display` to `block` will not reset their `animation`. Setting it to `none` will however.

So the easy fix is to set your elements `animation` property in the same place you set their `display: block;`.

```css
#tab1[type="radio"]:checked~#content1,
#tab2[type="radio"]:checked~#content2,
#tab3[type="radio"]:checked~#content3,
#tab4[type="radio"]:checked~#content4,
#tab5[type="radio"]:checked~#content5 {
  display: block;
  /* set the animation prop here */
  animation: fadeIn 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

#tab1[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label,
#tab2[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label,
#tab3[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label,
#tab4[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label,
#tab5[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label {
  color: #888;
}

#tab1[type="radio"]:checked+label,
#tab2[type="radio"]:checked+label,
#tab3[type="radio"]:checked+label,
#tab4[type="radio"]:checked+label,
#tab5[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  color: #000;
}

#tab1[type="radio"]:not(:checked)~#content1,
#tab2[type="radio"]:not(:checked)~#content2,
#tab3[type="radio"]:not(:checked)~#content3,
#tab4[type="radio"]:not(:checked)~#content4,
#tab5[type="radio"]:not(:checked)~#content5 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
<label for="tab1" class="pure-button"><span>section 1</span></label>
<input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label for="tab2" class="pure-button"><span>section 2</span></label>
<input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label for="tab3" class="pure-button"><span>section 3</span></label>
<input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label for="tab4" class="pure-button"><span>section 4</span></label>
<input id="tab5" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label for="tab5" class="pure-button"><span>section 5</span></label>
<div id="content1">
  <h1>content 1</h1>
</div>
<div id="content2">
  <h1>content 2</h1>
</div>
<div id="content3">
  <h1>content 3</h1>
</div>
<div id="content4">
  <h1>content 4</h1>
</div>
<div id="content5">
  <h1>content 5</h1>
</div>
```